# non-capturing parenthesis in "a or b" regex (operator precedence)

Tags: javascript, regex

Question: is this a bug, or is it my misunderstanding?

Here's a regexp that accepts "A red balloon" or "A blue balloon", shown in the node.js REP.  I'm using the 'non-capturing' ?: form since I'm not interested in capturing the color:

```
/A (?:red)|(?:blue) balloon!/.exec("A red balloon!")
=> [ 'A red', index: 0, input: 'A red balloon!' ]
```

So far, so good.  Now I want to match on red or blue 'ball' or 'balloon' or 'ballistic missile' or whatnot and capture that:

```
/A (?:red)|(?:blue) (ba.+)!/.exec("A red ball bearing!")
=> [ 'A red', undefined, index: 0, input: 'A red ball bearing!' ]
```

It matched, but it failed to capture the second form ('ball bearing'). (For what it's worth, the same form in regex101.com does NOT match.) To make it capture, I had to wrap the entire "or" clause in another non-capturing parentheses:

```
/A (?:(?:red)|(?:blue)) (ba.+)!/.exec("A red ball bearing!")
=> [ 'A red ball bearing!', 'ball bearing', index: 0, input: 'A red ball bearing!' ]
```

So the question: Why doesn't the second form work?  (Or why does it match in javascript and not in regex101.com?)  Why does introducing another non-capturing clause have any bearing on the subsequent capturing clause?  Or is this indicative of a bug?

Comment: Have you read the explanation on the top right corner of regex101? It explains the regex quite clearly.

Comment: @nhahtdh: the real issue is that of operator precedence, which regex101 doesn't address.  see amended answer.

Comment: Well, regex101 indeed doesn't say anything about operator precedence - your answer citing from MSDN answer that part. However, to understand the regex in the question (which is what you are actually asking), the tree structure in the explanation widget more or less tell what they do: http://i.stack.imgur.com/FQ1Kj.png

Comment: @nhahtdh: I appreciate your extra work in generating the screen shots.  However, if you look at the regex101 explanation for the *losing* case (`A (?:red)|(?:blue) (ba.+)!`), it really offers no insight as to why the regex is not working.  Happily, John Strom's answer made it clear.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I take it back: I stared at regex101's explanation long until I understood why it wasn't working.  And then I attained Samadhi.  It was lovely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's interpreting it as:

`A (?:red)`
OR
`(?:blue) (ba.+)!`

That's why it captured "A red". Once you added the parantheses, it captured correctly. It's just like order of operations.

With the parantheses, it became:

`A` `red OR blue` `ba.+` `!`

Comment: Ah -that makes sense, especially since `/A (?:red)|(?:blue) (ba.+)!/.exec("A blue ball bearing!")` => `[ 'blue ball bearing!', 'ball bearing', index: 2, input: 'A blue ball bearing!' ]`.  The Mozilla docs refer to the or operator as `a|b` without making reference to the binding strength of various operators.  Is operator precedence documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

[John Strom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4901945/john-strom) provided the correct answer: it comes down to a matter of operator precedence.  An authoritative list of operator precedence can be found [in the Microsoft Developer Network Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7h3k51c(v=vs.90).aspx) and other places.  In summary from highest precedence ('tightest binding') to lowest:

1. `\` (Escape)
2. `()`, `(?:)`, `(?=)`, `[]` (Parenthesis And Brackets)
3. `*`, `+`, `?`, `{n}`, `{n,}`, `{n,m}` (Quantifiers)
4. `^`, `$`, \anymetacharacter, anycharacter (Anchors and Sequences)
5. Consecutive non-special characters (Regular Characters)
6. `|` (Alternation)

As the MSDN documentation points out:

> Characters have higher precedence than the alternation operator, which allows `'m|food'` to match `"m"` or `"food"`. To match `"mood"` or `"food"`, use parentheses to create a subexpression, which results in `'(m|f)ood'`.

So the original example could be written more simply as:

```
/A (?:red|blue) (ba.*)!/
```

... which checks out properly in javascript and in regex101.